# Jetbrains' Team Tools Setup

Tags: nginx, http-proxy, upsource, jetbrains-hub

I have tried to install *Jetbrains' Team Tools* a couple of time, with sort of an success, but most of the features didn't work.

This time I purchased a separate server for couple of reasons, including nothing else being able to not make it work. but I think the real problem is me not understanding how to set it up correctly.

### What I did:

I'm running a `Linode` server with `Ubuntu 16.04` and have `nginx` installed.

> I have changed my real domain name with *example.com* in this question

#### Installing Hub

1. Downloaded and unzipped Jetbrains' Hub in `/opt/hub/`
2. Created a proxy to access the web page under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/jetbrains`

```
    ## Hub
    server {
        listen 2222;
        server_name hub.example.com;

        location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;

           proxy_pass http://localhost:1111;
        }
    }
```

3. Configured the Hub and ran it

```
    /opt/hub/bin/hub.sh configure --listen-port 1111 --base-url http://hub.example.com:2222

    /opt/hub/bin/hub.sh run --no-browser
```

4. Opened `http://hub.example.com:2222` and set it up.
5. Everything good so far. So I made the Hub service run on it's own from now on.

```
    /opt/hub/bin/hub.sh start
```

---

#### Same procedure for Upsource:

1. Downloaded and unzipped Jetbrains' Upsource in `/opt/upsource/`
2. Created a proxy to access the web page under the same file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/jetbrains`

```
    ## Hub
    server {
       ...
    }

    ## Upsource
    server {
        listen 2222;
        server_name upsource.example.com;

        location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;

           # to proxy WebSockets in nginx
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
           proxy_pass_header Sec-Websocket-Extensions;

           proxy_pass http://localhost:1112;
        }
    }
```

3. Configured and ran it

```
    /opt/upsource/bin/upsource.sh configure --listen-port 1112 --base-url http://upsource.example.com:2222

    /opt/upsource/bin/upsource.sh run --no-browser
```

4. Opened `http://upsource.example.com:2222` and set it up.
5. When asked for the Hub, I chose the external one and filled in `http://hub.example.com:2222` and it got verified.

After that you get the *Booting page* where it stopped when trying to start the `Upsource Frontend` with following log:

```
    * Starting Upsource Frontend 
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error] log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error] log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error] [2016-08-06 13:54:51,067] ERROR APP-WRAPPER] Proxy 1                 er.auth.api.AuthManagerFactory - Cannot configure Authentication module. HubUrlExt=http://hub.example.com:2222/hub, HubUrlInt=http://hub.example.com:2222/hub 
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error] javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Failed to convert a response into an exception.
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1033)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at jetbrains.jetpass.client.oauth2.OAuth2Client.getHubScope(OAuth2Client.java:54)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at jetbrains.jetpass.client.hub.HubClient.getAccountsClient(HubClient.java:118)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.server.auth.impl.HubProviderImpl.createAccountsClient(HubProviderImpl.java:392)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.server.auth.impl.HubProviderImpl.(HubProviderImpl.java:102)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.server.auth.api.AuthManagerFactory.createAuthManager(AuthManagerFactory.java:49)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.backend.server.facade.UpsourceApplicationEnvironment.buildMainContainer(UpsourceApplicationEnvironment.java:261)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.backend.server.facade.UpsourceApplicationEnvironment.(UpsourceApplicationEnvironment.java:97)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.backend.cli.UpsourceApplicationEnvironmentDaemonBase.startDaemon(UpsourceApplicationEnvironmentDaemonBase.java:13)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.backend.cli.UpsourceDaemonBase.start(UpsourceDaemonBase.java:144)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.backend.cli.UpsourceDaemonBase.start(UpsourceDaemonBase.java:234)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.upsource.frontend.server.UpsourceFrontendDaemon.start(UpsourceFrontendDaemon.java:83)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.launcher.AppProxy$6$1.call(AppProxy.java:99)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at com.jetbrains.launcher.AppProxy$6$1.call(AppProxy.java:97)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed.
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.ensureNotClosed(EntityInputStream.java:228)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.bufferEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:886)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.bufferEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:161)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:987)
    upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error]    ... 27 more
```

Thanks already for anyone wanting to help.

---

### Update

I set up upsource without using the external Hub and it still crashed.
Now I'm getting the error message when it starts booting the `upsource-monitor`.

The important lines are the 2 first ones

```
    upsource-cluster-init: [Upsource Cluster Initialize Service Error] log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
    upsource-cluster-init: [Upsource Cluster Initialize Service Error] log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running a 2GB RAM server instead of a 8GB RAM as the documentation mentioned. 8GB are a must apparently, services are too heavy for less.